# How to iterate through a list of dictionaries & pick one highest value

Tags: python, foursquare

I am working with the Foursquare Python library. Specifically I am working with the Specials. Specials has a key called Items, which is a list. The objects in the list are all dictionaries. It looks something like this:

```
list = [{'foo': 'ex', 'bar': 'ex', 'likes': {'count': 'x'}}, {'foo': 'ex', 'bar': 'ex', 'likes': {'count': 'x'}}, ...]
```

I want to iterate through this list, and compare the count for likes. Whichever dictionary object has the most likes, I want to pull out and store in a variable. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Don't name your variables `list` - you can't use it as the built-in function then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done with [max(iterable, key=...)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max), like

```
result = max( the_list, key=lambda item:item['likes']['count'] )
```

Comment: Also, as written item['likes']['count'] is a string - while this may not be the case in reality you may have to use `...int(item['likes']['count'])`

Comment: Awesome, this works great. Thanks so much. I wish I could up-vote your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for that:

```
print max(your_list, key=lambda val: int(val.get('likes', {}).get('count', 0)))
```

P.S.
do not use reserved names for your variables!